# Round Double to closest 10

Tags: swift, math, rounding

I would like to round a `Double` to the closest multiple of 10.

For example if the number is 8.0 then round to 10.
If the number is 2.0 round it to 0.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the `round()` function (which rounds a floating point number
to the nearest integral value) and apply a "scale factor" of 10:

```
func roundToTens(x : Double) -> Int {
    return 10 * Int(round(x / 10.0))
}
```

Example usage:

```
print(roundToTens(4.9))  // 0
print(roundToTens(15.1)) // 20
```

In the second example, `15.1` is divided by ten (`1.51`), rounded (`2.0`),
converted to an integer (`2`) and multiplied by 10 again (`20`).

**Swift 3:**

```
func roundToTens(_ x : Double) -> Int {
    return 10 * Int((x / 10.0).rounded())
}
```

Alternatively:

```
func roundToTens(_ x : Double) -> Int {
    return 10 * lrint(x / 10.0)
}
```

Answer (score 30):

defining the rounding function as

```
import Foundation

func round(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return round(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}
```

gives you more general and flexible way how to do it

```
let r0 = round(1.27, toNearest: 0.25)   // 1.25
let r1 = round(325, toNearest: 10)      // 330.0
let r3 = round(.pi, toNearest: 0.0001)  // 3.1416
```

UPDATE
more generic definitions

```
func round<T:BinaryFloatingPoint>(_ value:T, toNearest:T) -> T {
    return round(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}
func round<T:BinaryInteger>(_ value:T, toNearest:T) -> T {
    return T(round(Double(value), toNearest:Double(toNearest)))
}
```

and usage

```
let A = round(-13.16, toNearest: 0.25)
let B = round(8, toNearest: 3.0)
let C = round(8, toNearest: 5)

print(A, type(of: A))
print(B, type(of: B))
print(C, type(of: C))
```

prints

```
-13.25 Double
9.0 Double
10 Int
```

Comment: Nice general answer that is consistent with the existing round() method.  Should have more upvotes IMHO.

Answer (score 9):

You can also extend `FloatingPoint` protocol and add an option to choose the rounding rule:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func rounded(to value: Self, roundingRule: FloatingPointRoundingRule = .toNearestOrAwayFromZero) -> Self {
       (self / value).rounded(roundingRule) * value
    }
}
```

---

```
let value = 325.0
value.rounded(to: 10) // 330 (default rounding mode toNearestOrAwayFromZero)
value.rounded(to: 10, roundingRule: .down) // 320
```

Comment: Rounding to an arbitrary floating point value must be handled with care. For example, rounding to a multiple of 0.1 will in most cases product an “inexact” result because it cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.0 it is

```
10 * Int(round(Double(ratio / 10)))
```

Comment: `10 * Int(round(Double((325) / 10)))` Gives me 320. How can I obtain 330 if I'm halfway between ?

Answer (score 1):

Extension for rounding to any number !

```
extension Int{
   func rounding(nearest:Float) -> Int{
       return Int(nearest * round(Float(self)/nearest))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice extension for BinaryFloatingPoint in swift:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint{
    func roundToTens() -> Int{
        return 10 * Int(Darwin.round(self / 10.0))
    }

    func roundToHundreds() -> Int{
        return 100 * Int(Darwin.round(self / 100.0))
    }
}
```

Comment: `extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func roundToTens() -> Self {
        return (self / 10).rounded() * 10
    } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Double {
    var roundToTens: Double {
        let divideByTen = self / 10
        let multiByTen = (ceil(divideByTen) * 10)
        return multiByTen
    }
}
```

usage:
36. roundToTens