# Get 12h hours am/pm Time

Tags: swift, time, slider

I want to display the time from a Slider to a Label. So i must convert the value and get the current day time on it like 00:00 am/pm. 
So i need there a stepper how print all 5 steps like (5,10,15,20,25....50,55)
So this code on the bottom don´t run good, have anybody a better way to make that ?

I have try it but it becomes an error when i slider back (zb: when it´s 8:00 am and i slider back to 7:55 am it come for first 7:00 am.

Here is the code:

```
   func valueChange(_ sender: CircleSlider) {

    let countmin = Int(Double(sender.value) * 14.4)
    var hour = countmin / 60
    let mins = countmin - (hour*60)


    if hour >= 12 {
        hour -= 12
        Am.text = "Pm"
    } else {
        Am.text = "Am"
    }



    hours = hour


    let i = String(mins) 
    switch i {
        case "Nil":
            minutes = 00
        case "0":
            minutes = 00
        case "5":
            minutes = 05
        case "10":
            minutes = 10
        case "15":
            minutes = 15
        case "25":
            minutes = 25
        case "30":
            minutes = 30
        case "35":
            minutes = 35
        case "40":
            minutes = 40
        case "45":
            minutes = 45
        case "50":
            minutes = 50
        case "55":
            minutes = 55
        case "60":
            minutes = 60
        default:
            break
    }


    self.circleTime.text = "\(String(format: "%02d", hours!)):\(String(format: "%02d", minutes!))"
}
```

Thank´s for Help :)

Comment: What is the example value of Double(sender.value)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's an issue in your method for 7:56, 7:57, 7:58, 7:59 (it is not truncating well). This code should work for you:

```
func valueChange(_ sender: CircleSlider) {
    let countmin = Int(Double(sender.value) * 14.4)

    var hour = countmin / 60
    let mins = countmin - (hour * 60)

    if hour >= 12 {
        hour -= 12
        Am = "Pm"
    } else {
        Am = "Am"
    }

    hours = hour
    minutes = roundToFives(Double(mins))

    // This fixes when you have hh:60. For instance, it fixes 7:60 to 8:00
    if minutes == 60 {
        hours = hour + 1
        minutes = 0
    }

    self.circleTime.text = "\(String(format: "%02d", hours!)):\(String(format: "%02d", minutes!))"
}

// idea of this method comes from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922406/round-double-to-closest-10-swift
private func roundToFives(x : Double) -> Int {
    return 5 * Int(round(x / 5.0))
}
```