# How can I round Int to nearest 10 in Swift?

Tags: swift, int, double

I have a small problem in rounded numbers to the nearest 10

```
    var finalResult = Int(textfield.text!)

    let x = Double(finalResult)
    let y = x.rounded() / 5
    print(x) // 18.0
    print(y) // 3.6
```

i want result to be like this

```
     // if x = 6.0 ... 14.0
     // y = 2 

     // if x = 15.0
     // y = 3 

     // if x = 16.0 ... 24.0 
     // y = 4 

     // if x = 25.0
     // y = 5 

     // if x = 26.0 ... 34.0
     // y = 6
```

I hope I have asked a question that benefits me and others

I hope that I have explained the question well

Comment: All your examples are unclear to me. Rounding 6.0 ... 14.0 to the nearest 10 gives 10 – why do you expect the result to be y=2 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round Double to closest 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922406/round-double-to-closest-10).

Comment: Because y contains / 5

Comment: you could of made that example much clearer and easier to understand by not adding the / 5

Comment: thank u Martin R, I tried what I sent but I had a problem, if x = 15 rounded it to 20 and i want to stay 15 as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [round function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659131/1135154) and `x % 5 == 0` check.

```swift
let values = (6...100).map({ Double($0) })

func round(_ value: Double, toNearest: Double) -> Double {
    return round(value / toNearest) * toNearest
}

for x in values {
    if x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 5) == 0 {
        print("x - \(x), y - \(Int(x / 5))")
    } else {
        let rounded = round(x, toNearest: 10.0)
        print("x - \(x), y - \(Int(rounded / 5))")
    }
}
```