# Swift: create a range around a given number

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, range

**Question 1**

In my code I need to verify if a number (`Double` or `Int`) falls into a specific range around the number (with a specified tolerance).

For example, the center number is 15, the tolerance is 5, therefore the range is: `10-20`.

13, 18, 19 all fall into the range.

Currently I'm checking it in a following manner:

```
if (15 - unit)...(15 + unit) ~= accentedMinute {
  accentedMinute = 15
} else if (30 - unit)...(30 + unit) ~= accentedMinute {
  accentedMinute = 30
} else {
  accentedMinute = 45
}
```

I'm interested in using a simpler approach to tackle this problem, e.g.:

```
if Range(center: 15, tolerance: unit) ~= accentedMinute {
  accentedMinute = 15
} else if Range(center: 30, tolerance: unit) ~= accentedMinute {
...
```

**Question 2**

Maybe, this method could be simplified even further, the end goal is to "snap" the number to some closest number in a range.

For example, the set of numbers to snap to would be `0, 15, 30, 45, 60 (snaps to 0)`

Given a number `13` it should snap to `15`, and so forth.

Comment: Divide by 15, round to nearest integer, then multiply by 15 again. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/27922406/1187415.

Comment: What do you mean by closest ? What should be the snap of 16?

Comment: @LeoDabus 16 should snap to 15

Comment: By the way, `abs(unit - 15) <= tolerance`

Comment: @MartinR did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @Sulthan Those numbers were for reference purposes. The actual `unit` in the sample code was `7.5`

Comment: @RichardTopchiy That would still work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, how? With examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question one you can extend Range/ClosedRange and create a custom initialiser to behave as you want:

```
extension Range where Bound: AdditiveArithmetic & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(center: Bound, tolerance: Bound) {
        self.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: center - tolerance, upper: center + tolerance + 1))
    }
}
```

---

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound: AdditiveArithmetic {
    init(center: Bound, tolerance: Bound) {
        self.init(uncheckedBounds: (lower: center - tolerance, upper: center + tolerance))
    }
}
```

Regarding your question two about rounding, as already mentioned in comments you can multiply your value by `n`, round it and then divide by `n` again:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    func rounded(to value: Self, roundingRule: FloatingPointRoundingRule = .toNearestOrAwayFromZero) -> Self { (self/value).rounded(roundingRule) * value }
}
```

---

```
16.rounded(to: 15)  // 15
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the q1! I'm moving forward with the answer to the q2, since it's the problem that has to be solved.